# CSS styling links using id's and classes

Tags: css, class, styling

Is there a way of styling links using a id or a class without having to create a new selector for each individual element? for example
 something like this or close to this would be preferable

```
#logo {
    a: link {color: black}
    a: visited{color: black}
    a: hover{color: black}
}
```

However, the above syntax does not work instead all i can find is

```
#logo a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

#logo a:visited {
color: white
}

I feel like there's an easier way than this.

Comment: Sass can do this ( http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html , see Parent References) but it does require you to use involve extra tools so not easier per se.

Comment: I think that extra space after the colon will cause problems in some browsers.

Answer (score 11):

Heres how to do it to all links
I believe it should work:

```
#logo a:link,
#logo a:visited,
#logo a:hover {
   color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not all browser support the above methodology of separating the  tag styles with class or ID when you are dealing with different style in CSS with  tag in single page.

One can follow below method:

```
**If using ID with Field**
```

```css
a:link#myID {
    color: green;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
} 
a:visited#myID {
    color: pink;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover#myID {
    color: red;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active#myID {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```
    <a  href="#" target="_blank" ID="myID">Click Here</a> 

**If using Class with Field**
```

```css
a:link.myClass {
    color: green;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
} 
a:visited.myClass {
    color: pink;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover.myClass {
    color: red;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active.lx {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```
<a  href="#" target="_blank" class="myClass">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: so you can place the  class this way - a.class :link{ ..} or this way a:link.class {..} - and they both work?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly in css, but there are some projects that extend css

Check out sass:

http://sass-lang.com

Answer (score 0):

I also believe current CSS syntax is not all that optimal. My personal choice is to go with something like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) where you get much more intuitive and compact syntax to style your work.

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS you must specify each pseudo-selector but you can group them to apply the same style attributes;

```
#logo a:link,
#logo a:visited,
#logo a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

Beware that [The order of link pseudo-classes matters](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200811/the_order_of_link_pseudo-classes_matters/).